Automate Week Number based on the criteria
Please help me on how to automate the sequence based on the value on the other column.
So on column B is the week number should be automated based on the value of the column A, If the value on column A is TRUE then it should increment else retain the value above.
I already have a formula on column B but I can't find a correct solution on how to make it automated similar to the value on the column B.
Below is the google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ji8gGuWm2xfrLzTwCfeJ3UKmFaI_dsFyHFVrAriBYnI/edit?usp=sharing


Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange.

Clear cells B3:B and put this formula in cell B3:
=scan(B2, A3:A, lambda(a, c, a + c))

The sequence will extend all the way to the bottom of the sheet. To make it show blanks on blank rows, use this:
=scan(B2, A3:A, lambda(a, c, 
  if(isblank(c), 
    iferror(ø), 
    a + c 
  ) 
))

See scan().
